# Extracting "extra" docstrings from Python code?

Tags: python, docstring

Python docstrings that immediately follows the declaration of a class or function are placed in the `__doc__` attribute.

The Question: How does one extract additional "internal" docstrings that occur later on in a function?

Update: Such literal statements are elided by the compiler.  Could I perhaps get to them (and their line number) via the AST?

---

Why do I ask?

I've had a (not fully baked) idea to use such "internal" docstrings to delineate Given/When/Then sections of an Agile Scenario:

```
def test_adding():
    """Scenario: Adding two numbers"""
    adder = Adder()
    """When I add 2 and 3"""
    result = adder.add(2, 3)
    """Then the result is 5"""
    assert result == 5
```

By extracting the docstrings, the test-running framework could generate output like this:

```
Scenario: Adding two numbers
   When I add 2 and 3 (PASS)
   Then the result is 5 (FAIL)

AssertionError   Traceback
...
```

I think this would be more concise than the approach taken in [Behave](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave), [Freshen](https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen), [Lettuce](http://packages.python.org/lettuce/tutorial/simple.html), [PyCukes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycukes/0.1.2), which require defining a separate function for each step.  I don't like having to repeat the text of the step as a function name (`@When("I add numbers") def add_numbers()`).  But unlike a plain unit test, the docstrings will add the ability to print out a business-readable scenario for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could parse your tests using the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module, and manually walk the tree and setup tests, etc. There are probably better ways of doing this (you could use `ast.NodeVisitor` or `ast.NodeTransfomer` and the visitor pattern perhaps), but here's an example:

```
import ast, inspect

def find_tests(module):
    # generate AST from module's source
    tree = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(module))
    # return tests in module, assuming they are top level function definitions
    return [node for node in tree.body if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]

def print_docstrings(test):
    for node in test.body:
        if isinstance(node, ast.Expr):
            # print lineno and docstring
            print node.value.lineno, node.value.s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import test_adding
    for test in find_tests(test_adding):
        print_docstrings(test)
```

You might also be interested in [konira](http://konira.cafepais.com/docs/index.html).

Comment: you could use `inspect.getsource(module)` to get source. you don't need `_ast` the names are available via `ast`.

Comment: I'm not sure you should go the `ast` route since it is essentially introducing new syntax for your tests. What if someone forgets to put the string? etc. 

Maybe you can specify contexts using the `with` statement and use those to build up the overall test.

Comment: Personally I think it's relatively harmless, but it does bring to mind konira, which the asker might be interested in.

Comment: Valuable comments. I guess simply printing out steps is probably better achieved with just function calls, even simpler than with-statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, since the compiler elides literal statements.

```
>>> def foo():
...   'docstring'
...   3
...   'bar'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Oh well, back to the drawing board.